# Stack Overflow infrastructure

Tags: discussion, support

Just curious what is infrastructure behind Stack Overflow?  Programming languages, external dependencies, and etc.  Also, does Stack Overflow use bare metal, VM's, a cloud provider (IaaS or Paas).

Answer (score 1):

[Bare metal with some VMs](http://blog.serverfault.com/2015/03/05/how-we-upgrade-a-live-data-center/).

The hardware list could use an update, but most of the info on our stack can be found here: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Our sysadmin team also recently did a Reddit AMA that you can read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/2zd9lz/we_keep_stack_exchange_stack_overflow_server/).